# Plumber accepting a file and a string file name

Tags: r, httr, plumber

I am trying to create a `R` `plumber` endpoint that accepts both an `.rds` file and a string representing a filename to use when saving to disk. I have been successful with the below example however every request has plumber reporting the following message

```
No suitable parser found to handle request body type .
```

How can I achieve my goal of parsing an `.rda` file and string to a plumber api in the "correct" way with no messages and preferably also with `swagger` support?

### Example plumber api

plumber.R

```r
library(plumber)
#* Save an rds file to disk
#* @post /write_rds
#* @parser multi
#* @parser rds
#* @parser text
#* @parser none
function(req) {
  multi <- mime::parse_multipart(req)
  
  file_path <- multi$file_path
  rds_file <- readRDS(multi$rds_file$datapath)
  
  save(rds_file,file = file_path)
  TRUE 
}
```

Request made with httr package

```r
library(magrittr)
library(httr)

tmpfile <- tempfile()
saveRDS(iris,file =  tmpfile)

res <- 
  POST(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8966/write_rds",
    body = list(
      # send the file with mime type `"application/rds"` so the RDS parser is used
      rds_file = upload_file(tmpfile, "application/rds"),
      file_path="test.rds"
    ),encode = "multipart"
  ) %>%
  content()
res
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to have stop the message appearing however I do not believe this is the cleanest solution. It turns out the `#* @parser rds` tags are not necessary when pulling from the `req` object. The downside of the solution below is that the other arguments to the R function are not provided and must be extracted from `req`

### Working example plumber .R file

```r
library(plumber)

#* Save an rds file to disk
#* @post /write_rds
#* @param rds_file:[file]
#* @param file_path:[str]
function(req, rds_file, file_path) {

  multi <- mime::parse_multipart(req)
  # function does not receive the `file_path` argument 
  # despite being in the post body
  cat("file_path is '", file_path, "'\n")
  #multi contains a list with enough info to get POST content 
  str(multi)
  #extract `file_path` from request body
  file_path <- multi$file_path
  #read the content of the rds (in this case, head(iris))
  rds_file <- readRDS(multi$rds_file$datapath)
  print(rds_file)
  #write to disk
  saveRDS(rds_file, file = file_path)
  TRUE
}
```

### httr request

```r
library(magrittr)
library(httr)

tmpfile <- tempfile()
dat <- head(iris)
saveRDS(dat,file =  tmpfile)

res <- 
  POST(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8966/write_rds",
    body = list(
      # send the file with mime type `"application/rds"` so the RDS parser is used
      rds_file = upload_file(tmpfile, "application/rds"),
      file_path="testfile.rds"
    ),encode = "multipart"
  ) %>%
  content()
res
```